# openssl 1.0.2g build results in linker errors after adding new symmetric cipher

Tags: c, linker, openssl

I have integrated a custom 256bit symmetric cipher into the source of OpenSSL 1.0.2g (the ubuntu version); and now i'm facing linker errors building openssl apps. My new cipher is called MYCIPH or myciph. The format for the modifications are as follows:

```
<Filename>

x*  <Code> 

*x indicates the Line No. for the modification/insertion
```

The modifications are as follows:

```
openssl/Makefile.org:
97  MYCIPH_ENC= myciph_enc.o
...

144 # dirs in crypto to build
145 SDIRS= \
...
148 des aes rc2 rc4 rc5 idea bf myciph cast camellia seed
...
231 MYCIPH_ENC= ‘$(MYCIPH_ENC)’


crypto/evp/Makefile:
22  e_des.c e_bf.c e_myciph.c e_idea.c …
...
35  e_des.o e_bf.o e_myciph.o e_idea.o …

obj_mac.num:*
958 myciph 958

objects.txt:
421 1 3 3 7 : MYCIPH  : myciph

evp.h:
87  # define EVP_MAX_IV_LENGTH  32

782 #endif
783 #ifndef OPENSSL_NO_MYCIPH
784 const EVP_CIPHER *EVP_myciph(void);
785 #endif
786 # ifndef OPENSSL_NO_RC4

c_allc.c:
145 #ifndef OPENSSL_NO_MYCIPH
146 EVP_add_cipher(EVP_myciph());
147 EVP_add_cipher_alias(SN_drgn_bd,"myciph");
148 EVP_add_cipher_alias(SN_drgn_bd,"MYCIPH");

149 #endif
```

Here are the contents of my `e_myciph.c` file inside `OPENSSL_ROOT/crypto/evp/`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "cryptlib.h"

#ifndef OPENSSL_NO_MYCIPH

#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/objects.h>
#include <openssl/mycipher.h>

static int myciph_init_key(EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx, const unsigned char *key,
            const unsigned char *iv,int enc);
static int myciph_cipher(EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx, unsigned char *out,
              const unsigned char *in, size_t inl);
static const EVP_CIPHER mycipher_cipher=
    {
    NID_myciph,
    1, 32, 32,  
    EVP_CIPH_VARIABLE_LENGTH,
    myciph_init_key,
    myciph_cipher,
    NULL,
    32,
    NULL,
    EVP_CIPHER_set_asn1_iv,
    EVP_CIPHER_get_asn1_iv,
    NULL
    };
const EVP_CIPHER *EVP_myciph(void)
    {
    return(&myciph_cipher);
    }

static int myciph_init_key(EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx, const unsigned char *key,
            const unsigned char *iv, int enc)
    {
......
    }

static int myciph_cipher(EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx, unsigned char *out,
              const unsigned char *in, size_t inl)
    {
......
    }
#endif
```

Other files changed included:

```
ssl_algs.c:
 81 #ifndef OPENSSL_NO_MYCIPH
82 EVP_add_cipher(EVP_myciph());
83 #endif


ssl_locl.h:
357 # define SSL_MYCIPH   0x00004000L

ssl_ciph.c:
167 # define SSL_ENC_MYCIPH_IDX 14
168 # define SSL_ENC_NUM_IDX 15

172 static const EVP_CIPHER*ssl_cipher_methods[SSL_ENC_NUM_IDX]={
173 NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,
NULL, NULL
174 };

305 {0, SSL_TXT_MYCIPH, 0, 0, 0, SSL_MYCIPH, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},

//void ssl_load_ciphers(void){
407 ssl_cipher_methods[SSL_ENC_MYCIPH_IDX]= EVP_get_cipherbyname(SN_myciph);

//int ssl_cipher_get_evp(...){
//switch (c->algorithm_enc){
585 case SSL_MYCIPH:
586 i = SSL_ENC_MYCIPH_IDX;
587 break;

675 else if (c->algorithm_enc == SSL_MYCIPH &&
676 (evp=EVP_get_cipherbyname("MYCIPH")))
677 *enc = evp, *md = NULL;


796 *enc |= (ssl_cipher_methods[SSL_ENC_MYCIPH_IDX ] ==
NULL) ? SSL_MYCIPH :0;

1784 case SSL_MYCIPH:
1785 enc="MYCIPH(256)"; 
1786 break;

s3_lib.c:
604 {
605 1,
606 SSL3_TXT_RSA_MYCIPH,
607 SSL3_CK_RSA_MYCIPH,
608 SSL_kRSA,
609 SSL_aRSA,
610 SSL_MYCIPH,
611 SSL_MD5,
612 SSL_SSLV3,
613 SSL_NOT_EXP|SSL_MEDIUM,
614 SSL_HANDSHAKE_MAC_DEFAULT|TLS1_PRF,
615 256, //Key-Size (bits)
616 256, //IV-Size (bits)
617 },

ssl.h:
              300 # define SSL_TXT_MYCIPH "MYCIPH”

ssl3.h:
179 # define SSL3_CK_RSA_MYCIPH 0x0300001C
...
254 # define SSL3_TXT_RSA_MYCIPH "MYCIPH"

apps/prog.pl:
85  "cast-cbc", "rc5-cbc", "rc5-ecb", "rc5-cfb", "rc5-ofb",
86  "myciph", )
```

After I changed these files. Compiling using `./config fips; make depend; make` was successful and the apps can link nicely. I even manage to test my cipher via the EVP interface: `openssl speed -evp myciph`.

However, when I build by configuring with `./config fips shared; make depend; make;` to generate shared objects for `libcrypto` and `libssl` I get the following linker error:

```
making all in apps...
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/wanghao/Documents/iVPN/openssl_new/openssl-1.0.2g/apps'
rm -f openssl
shlib_target=; if [ -n "libcrypto.so.1.0.2 libssl.so.1.0.2" ]; then \
    shlib_target="linux-shared"; \
elif [ -n "" ]; then \
  FIPSLD_CC="gcc"; CC=/usr/local/ssl/fips-2.0/bin/fipsld; export CC FIPSLD_CC; \
fi; \
LIBRARIES="-L.. -lssl  -L.. -lcrypto" ; \
make -f ../Makefile.shared -e \
    APPNAME=openssl OBJECTS="openssl.o verify.o asn1pars.o req.o dgst.o dh.o dhparam.o enc.o passwd.o gendh.o errstr.o ca.o pkcs7.o crl2p7.o crl.o rsa.o rsautl.o dsa.o dsaparam.o ec.o ecparam.o x509.o genrsa.o gendsa.o genpkey.o s_server.o s_client.o speed.o s_time.o apps.o s_cb.o s_socket.o app_rand.o version.o sess_id.o ciphers.o nseq.o pkcs12.o pkcs8.o pkey.o pkeyparam.o pkeyutl.o spkac.o smime.o cms.o rand.o engine.o ocsp.o prime.o ts.o srp.o" \
    LIBDEPS=" $LIBRARIES -ldl" \
    link_app.${shlib_target}
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/wanghao/Documents/iVPN/openssl_new/openssl-1.0.2g/apps'
../libssl.so: undefined reference to `EVP_myciph'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
../Makefile.shared:171: recipe for target 'link_app.gnu' failed
make[2]: *** [link_app.gnu] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/wanghao/Documents/iVPN/openssl_new/openssl-1.0.2g/apps'
Makefile:156: recipe for target 'openssl' failed
make[1]: *** [openssl] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/wanghao/Documents/iVPN/openssl_new/openssl-1.0.2g/apps'
Makefile:297: recipe for target 'build_apps' failed
make: *** [build_apps] Error 1
```

Did I miss out anything I have to change? Were my changes correct? please advise thanks.

EDIT:
After asking someone (Ben) on OpenSSL-dev mailing list, it appears the Debian packaging adds a layer that uses and export symbol list to restrict what symbols can be used from the shared library; it seems Ubuntu has also picked up that bit of code.  After editing openssl.ld in the source tree by adding EVP_myciph to the list of symbols, compiling completed without issues.

Comment: I believe you have to perform a `make dclean` to avoid old configurations. Also, you probably want to avoid `./config fips`. There are some non-obvious interactions going on with `fipscanister.o` and the OpenSSL capable library. Finally, you might want to share both the declaration and implementation stub for `EVP_flcn_bd` since its a pain point.

Comment: @jww, tried dclean and rebuild. Still the same. actually EVP_myciph is the undefined reference (edited qns). Anyway, building without ./config fips revealed `error FIPS is disabled`. Any idea how to build without errors and fips?

Comment: hello there, hope you;re good. I am adding my custom cipher and getting this same error [1.0.1u version is required to be used]? I am unable to find the "openssl.ld" file ? Where is this located ?

Comment: PING !!! !!! !!!